# How can I change a list in a dictionary into a key and he's value?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{
  'brand' : 'toyota'
  'model' : 'corolla'
  'specs' : ['motor', 'cil', 'hp']
  'des_spec' : [2.4, 4, 187]
}
```

And I want that dictionary look like this:

```
{
  'brand' : 'toyota'
  'model' : 'corolla'
  'motor' : 2.4
  'cil'  : 4
  'hp'  : 187
}
```

How can I change that lists?. Thank you

Comment: What have you done to change the same? Please provide your code.
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `d.update(dict(zip(d["specs"], d["des_spec"])))`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need it flexible for other cases, you could just do...

```py
a = {
  'brand' : 'toyota'
  'model' : 'corolla'
  'specs' : ['motor', 'cil', 'hp']
  'des_spec' : [2.4, 4, 187]
}

t = 0 # Counter

for spec in a["specs"]: # Loop over the specs
    a[spec] = des_spec[t] # Insert into dictionary, key from spec, value from des_spec
    t += 1 # Up the counter
```

Comment: You miss a line to define `des_spec = a['des_spec']`. Also, for a more pythonic way, the counter can be avoided by using `for spec, val in zip(a['specs'], a['des_spec']:`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dict.pop` with `zip`

**Ex:**

```
data = {
  'brand' : 'toyota',
  'model' : 'corolla',
  'specs' : ['motor', 'cil', 'hp'],
  'des_spec' : [2.4, 4, 187]
}
for k, v in zip(data.pop('specs'), data.pop('des_spec')):
    data[k] = v

print(data)
# --> {'brand': 'toyota', 'cil': 4, 'hp': 187, 'model': 'corolla', 'motor': 2.4}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d1 = {
  'brand' : 'toyota',
  'model' : 'corolla',
  'specs' : ['motor', 'cil', 'hp'],
  'des_spec' : [2.4, 4, 187]
}
d2 = defaultdict()
for k,v in d1.items():
    if type(v)!=list:
        d2[k]=v
d3 = dict(zip(d1['specs'],d1['des_spec']))
d2.update(d3)
for k,v in d2.items():
    print(k,v)

#brand toyota
#model corolla
#motor 2.4
#cil 4
#hp 187
```

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
d.update(dict(zip(d["specs"], d["des_spec"]))) #it will update the dictionary by adding spec's values as key and des_spec's values as value.
d.pop('specs')
d.pop('des_spec')  #it will remove des_spec key:pair from the dictionary.
print(d)
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps